# divs full width center aligned without scroll

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm looking for a way of doing the following in css. I have 3 divs stacked vertically. I'd like them to be full width and positioned so the middle div (shown in blue) is always in the center of the screen. I'd like the two outer divs (shown in red) to be the same width but go out of the bounds of the window without scrolling. I can manage it horizontally but not vertically for some reason. I'm using tailwind but happy to see plain css solutions if anyone has one.

[image: layout]

The following tailwind markup almost works but does not position the divs so the middle one is always in the center.

```
<div class="flex justify-center align-middle items-center h-screen">
  <div class="h-auto w-screen my-auto">
    <div class="flex flex-col justify-center align-middle items-center w-full h-auto overflow-hidden">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200" class="shrink-0 w-full aspect-square" />
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200" class="shrink-0 w-full aspect-square" />
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/200" class="shrink-0 w-full aspect-square" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you tell me if you want it to be vertically scrollable or not?

Comment: No, I'd like it not to scroll @Nikkkshit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work as described. Fun challenge. I use container to center content on the page. Add absolute position to content to allow overflow top and display it as flex with vertical direction.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

.container{
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.content{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.pink{
    height: 20vw;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgb(255, 129, 150);
}
.blue{
    height: 40vw;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="pink"></div>
                <div class="blue"></div>
                <div class="pink"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex` set container to flexible and than `flex-direction:column` which is by default `row` set items in the vertical direction. 
`flex` which is short hand property of `flex-grow` `flex-shrink` `flex-basis` help use to set how much space flex-item will take inside of flexcontainer.
I have use class **.flex2** to set middle `div` to take  **twice the amount of space**(if you want more space change value of `flex:2` to more or less as per your requirement) from other flex item.
I have given height explicitly to row as to distribute amount of space you can play with that value.

```css
.main {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}

.row>div {
  flex: 1;
}

.row>div.container {
  flex: 6;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  word-break: break-all;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      head
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata
      data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data
      datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata
      data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data
      datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata
      data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data
      datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata
      data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data
      datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata
      data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata
      data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data
      datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata
      data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data
      datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata
      data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data
      datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata
      datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data
      datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata data datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata
      <div>
        datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata
      </div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x150"> datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatada
      datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatada
      datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatada
    </div>
    <div>
      foot
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question was not clear but I would like the center div to always be in the middile of the browser window.

Comment: I have changed the answer